# Given a positive integer $m$, what is the smallest number $n$ such that $S_n$ contains an element of order $m$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations

This was a question on a midterm I recently took, but I didn't do well on it (the question I mean), so I'd like to figure out the idea. I thought that since the order of a composition of disjoint cycles has order LCM of the individual orders that I might first write $m = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{e_i}$ as its prime factorization. But there I'm not sure where to go. Is just taking the LCM of the $p_i$ as our $n$ good enough, or is there something more? Hints/ideas are fine.

Comment: I think that the answer would be $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} p_i^{e_i}$$ but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Dylan: Looks good to me.